# React Naitve Error - Invariant Violation: ART has been removed from React Native

Tags: react-native

ART was imported from 'react-native' in the react-native-progress module.

```
import { Animated, ART, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
```

I updated the module and now it imported from @react-native-community/art.

```
import { Surface as ARTSurface } from '@react-native-community/art';
```

ART is not used in the project anywhere else, yet I am still facing the same error.
Any idea what's wrong?

Error Message:
Invariant Violation: ART has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/art' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/art.

[Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lFRt.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your stack trace, You are using react-native-progress and this is an internal dependency of it and that's why you are facing this issue.

According to docs of react-native-progress.

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress/blob/master/README.md#reactart-based-components

So according to docs, you can remove it too for fixing this error.

`Note: If you don't want the ReactART-based components and their dependencies, do a deep require instead: import ProgressBar from 'react-native-progress/Bar';.`

So either you can avoid using these components which are `ART` based or try to fix them like below.

```
in file Circle.js, CircleSnail.js, Pie.js,
replace ART.Surface with
import {Surface} from '@react-native-community/art';
and in file Shapes/Arc.js
import {Shape, Path} from '@react-native-community/art';
and replace the same above.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this answer , Im not using those circle , Pie etc.. Still facing this issue.

Comment: @Kartiikeya just imports the specific module instead of the whole library.

Answer (score 1):

Any package relies on ART will cause the issue with you , not only **react-native-progress** , but also packages with loaders like this **react-native-loading-spinner-overlay** ,
You can change this by finding another package of by fixing your imports

The Art library has been removed as of SDK 36 ,
If you need to use react-native-progress, which relies on ART, you can use the bare workflow and install [@react-native-community/art](https://github.com/react-native-community/art), or implement your own progress indicator using Svg